# How to solve more complex wp_query meta_query with WP title

Tags: mysql, wordpress

If I were using a SQL statement, this is what it would look like:

```
select * from courses where active = 1 AND (title = $string OR description = $string)
```

'courses' is a custom post type

'active' is a custom field created with ACF

'description' is a custom field created with ACF

'title' is the standard WP title for posts

This is what I have so far:

```
$args_courses = array(
                'post_type' => 'courses',
                'posts_per_page' => 9999,
                'meta_query' => array(
                        array(
                            'key' => 'active',
                            'value' => 1,
                            'compare' => '='
                        ),  
                        'relation' => 'AND',
                        array(
                            'key' => 'description',
                            'value' => $string,
                            'compare' => '='
                        ),
                        'relation' => 'OR',
                        array(
                            'key' => 'title',
                            'value' => $string,
                            'compare' => '='    
                        )
                ),
            );
```

It seems as though I can't access the WP title through a meta_query, but can't figure out how to turn my query around so 'active' remains the first column to check on.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is not supported by the default `WP_Query` functionality, however you can extend it as described in the following answer from the WordPress Stackexchange site. Note that you you may need to alter it further for your specific use case.

> https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/178484/wp-query-args-title-or-meta-value

A few notes on your current query.

- `relation` should only be used once in your `meta_query`. WordPress uses arrays to do the grouping, and wouldn't know to use "AND" or "OR" in your example.
- It looks like you want "all" posts, not really `9999` posts, so you should use `-1` to fetch everything in one result set.